# $x_n \in \mathbb R, \quad x_n \to A \implies \max \{x_n,A-x_n\} \to ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am stuck on the following problem that is as follows:

> Let $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of real numbers converging to $A \neq 0.$ Let $y_n=\max \{x_n,A-x_n\}$.Then the limit of the sequence  $\{y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is always

1. $0$
2. $ A  $
3. $\max \{A,0\}$
4. $-\min \{A,0\}$

I do not know how to progress with the problem.Can someone point me in the right direction?Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Isn't $x\mapsto \max(x,A-x)$ a continuous function ?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* if $f$ is a continuous function and $x_n\to A$ then $f(x_n)\to f(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Try examples and think of the general case:

1) A monotone descending sequence

$$\frac{n+1}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

2) A monotone increasing sequence

$$\frac{n}{n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1$$

3) Non monotone sequence

$$\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

4) Non-monotone sequence converging to $\,A\neq 0\,$:

$$1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\ldots$$

Comment: Don't forget for the third one that $A$ is different from $0$
Edit : I hadn't seen the fourth one. My bad

Comment: Thanks for the comment anyway, @mwoua. I *really* missed that, though it came out awright.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x_{n}\to A$, then $A-x_{n}\to 0$. Since $A\neq 0$, then you find $\varepsilon>0$ so that $B(A,\varepsilon)\cap B(0,\varepsilon)=\emptyset$. By definition of convergence we find $n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $x_{n}\in B(A,\varepsilon)$ and $A-x_{n}\in B(0,\varepsilon)$ for all $n\geq n_{\varepsilon}$.

1. If $A<-\varepsilon$, then $y_{n}=\max\{x_{n},A-x_{n}\}=A-x_{n}$ for all $n\geq n_{\varepsilon}$, whence $y_{n}\to 0=\max\{A,0\}$.
2. And if $A>\varepsilon$, then $y_{n}=\max\{x_{n},A-x_{n}\}=x_{n}$ for all $n\geq n_{\varepsilon}$, whence $y_{n}\to A=\max\{A,0\}$.

Since $A\notin B(0,\varepsilon)$ then 1. and 2. cover all the possible cases. Hence $y_{n}\to \max\{A,0\}$.

Comment: And with $B(x,\varepsilon)$ I of course mean the $\varepsilon$-radius ball around $x$.